# Using fetch() returns index.html (no Framework, serving with Parcel)

Tags: javascript, html, indexing, fetch, parcel

I am trying to build a javascript program and am serving it with Parcel during development. Using fetch() always returns the index.html.
The *.abc file is a music markdown format. The files needed will be provided by the program, not by the user (no files on the users hardrive are involved).

```
import abcjs from "abcjs";

 async function rendering() {
    let score = await fetch("./omnibook/Buzzy.abc");
    let score_text = await score.text();
    console.log(score_text);
    let parsed = await abcjs.renderAbc("paper", score_text);
    console.log(parsed);
}

rendering();
```

If I use light-server instead of parcel, fetch() works fine, but it can't resolve the abcjs import.

Comment: You can't `fetch` arbitrary files like that, unless you have a server that is explicitly set up to do so, which is a terrible idea. Set up a server route that reads the file you want from disk and returns the data. Stuff in `/public` can probably be served *if* it is a file that is normally loaded by a web page like Javascript or CSS and it is requested via a script or link tag as appropriate (NOT fetch).

Comment: What is buzzy.abc? And are you sure buzzy is in your public folder? Anyway, fetch should primarily be used for fetching JSON or perhaps XML

Comment: Buzzy.abc is a abc file (abc is a markdown-language for music notation). I was using fetch, because it was used for audio files in a tutorial I read through a few months ago. I also tried using XMLHttpRequest, which I saw in another example using the same library for abc files. However, that also returns my index.html...
Maybe I shoult add that these are NOT files that should be uploaded from the users machine. They should be stored on the server and loaded into the script from there.

Comment: Ah ok. So `fetch` is not going to be able to return arbitrary files like that. Typically (and this will vary somewhat depending on what server side tech you use) you will set up a route with an endpoint like "/music/somefilename" and when serving that request your server will read the file from the disk and send back a string with the contents, and then you can feed that to something that knows what to do with it (quick google search suggested https://github.com/paulrosen/abcjs).